# IE 8 and text fading

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem with fading text in IE 8, 7 and 6 (obviously). The text has a black outline during the animation that completely ruins the effect. Is there a workaround? I've read a bunch of answers about this problem and none made sense. Please take a look at this simple jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LhSK7/ in IE 8, and show me how to fix it if possible.

Edit: screenshot of the problem: http://i43.tinypic.com/1z6h1th.png
I thought it might be because of the VirtualBox, but all other browsers display it correctly in VirtualBox.

Edit #2: the problem can *sort of* be solved by setting the background color of the element being faded, which while still pretty ugly in IE 8 and below, at least gets rid of the black outline.

Comment: I've tried calling this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); after the animation finishes as recommended, but it has no effect. I don't even know if it applies to this problem because the problem is _during_ the animation

Comment: I don't see any problems in IE 8,7,6 with this method. there is no 'black outline' that I can see. Could u screenshot for us?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the screenshot. The outline is black when it's almost at full opacity, before it reverts to the normal, cleartype text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set a background colour to #content, that should work (at least in IE8, I don't have older versions at hand to check).

Answer (score 0):

Add microsoft filter to your "container" and you will get smooth animation:) 
You can even put it in between IE only tags...

```
<!--[if IE]>
#container {
 font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;font-size:40px;
 display:block;
 width:400px;
 height:80px;
 border:1px solid;
 position:relative; 
 color:#a0a0a0;
 background-color:white; 
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; 
 filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
 }
 <![endif]-->
```